# Ubuntu 12.04 and SSH: Automatically shutting down another computer when powering off

Tags: 12.04, ssh, shutdown, init.d

I want to shut down another computer in my network when shutting down my own.

For that I have created a script that logs into that machine through `ssh` and powers it off. (SSH keys are set up, so no need for password.)

```
#! /bin/sh
ssh user@remote sudo halt
```

And placed it in `/etc/init.d`.

Then I created two symlinks pointing to this file under `rc0.d` and `rc6.d` called `K10haltremote.sh`.

If I call the script manually it works as expected, but when shutting down or rebooting my machine does not have any effect on the remote one.

The only thing I can figure out is that shutdown is too fast, and there is not time for the ssh connection, but it's only a guess.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check the order of scripts being executed during shutdown? maybe your network connection is cut before the ssh command? As a test you could let your script a) write random text to a file to see if it really is executed, b) make the script do a network test (ifconfig output, ping whatever) and write the output to a file, so that you know if you still have an active network connection during script execution.

Comment: Many thanks. Outputting some info in a txt file I realised the file was created by su instead of my user, and helped to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The thing I didn't take into account is that the script is exectuted as root and not with my user. So when running ssh, password is required as I only set up the keys for my user.
The workaround I used is forcing ssh to use my user keys:

```
ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa user@remote sudo halt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh user@remote sudo halt & sleep 10
```